# Query Question (automation failed due to system error)

Tags: marketing-cloud, sql

THe code below is throwing an error "failed due to system error" - is it because of the subquery?

I double checked my DE's data types and length - looks good but this is throwing an error

```
SELECT user_Id,
value_2, 
(SELECT city from IGO_PROFILES  where city = 'riga' 
) as cityoption

from IGO_PROFILES
```

Comment: Sounds dumb, but try the same query again. Query studio likes to throw this error intermittently. Also you can just build a quick target DE and try it in automation studio, or without the DE at least validate the syntax.

Comment: Yep i did build a target DE still throwing an error :P haha will give it another shot

Answer (score 0):

That query studio error - "automation failed due to system error" shows up intermittently - Sounds dumb, but try the same query again.

Also you can just build a quick target DE and try it in automation studio, or without the DE at least validate the syntax.

That aside, looking at the query itself:

I would use a CASE statement if I understand your intention right:
Select *all* users, but fill 'riga' into cityOption field in case 'riga' is in the city field.

```
SELECT 
user_Id
,value_2
,CASE WHEN city = 'riga' THEN
    city
ELSE
    ''
END AS cityOption

from IGO_PROFILES
```